# Splitting an array equally:

Tags: php, count

I have the following array:

```
$array = array(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1);
```

I want split it up into individual arrays so that each array contains seven or less values.

So for example the first array will become:

```
$one = array(1,0,0,0,1,1,1)
$two = array(1,0,1,1,1,1,0)
$three = array(1,1,0,1,0,0,1);
$four = array(0,1);
```

Also how would you count the number of times 1 occurs in array one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk) is what you are looking for.

```
 $splitted = array_chunk($array, 7);
```

For counting the occurences I would be lazy. If your arrays only contain `1`s or `0`s, then a simple [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/array_sum) would do:

```
 print array_sum($splitted[0]);    // for the first chunk
```

Comment: PHP's array functions never cease to amaze (in a "I can't believe they actually took the trouble to put that in" kind of way).

Answer (score 3):

> I want split it up into individual arrays so that each array contains seven or less values.

Use [`array_chunk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php), which is made expressly for this purpose.

> Also how would you count the number of times 1 occurs in array one?

Use [`array_count_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

```
$one = array(1,0,0,0,1,1,1);
$one_counts = array_count_values($one);
print_r($one_counts);

// prints
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to preserve the contents of the array, I'd use array_slice() to extract the needed number of elements from the array, incrementing the '$offset' by the required count each time until the array was exhausted.

And as to your second question, try:

```
$num_ones=count(preg_grep(/^1$/,$array));
```